# MSDEPLOY; Trying to Keep app pools and sites on destination server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-6, windows-server-2008, msdeploy

I'm trying to use msdeploy to migrate all existing websites on a source=server 2003 (Server1) IIS6 to destination=server 2008 R2 (Server2) IIS 7.5, but keep all existing websites on Server2. I've installed msdeploy on both Server1 and Server2 servers.

I started with the command line on Server2:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver60,computerName=Server1 -dest:webserver60 -whatif > msdeploy_test.log
```

The log indicates that it is deleting the existing app pools on Server2. I ran the same command line without "-whatif" and it did delete all existing websites on Server2.

I next tried, -SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true, command line on Server2:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver60,computerName=Server1 -dest:webserver60 -skipextrafilesonserver=true -whatif > msdeploy_test.log.
```

This returned a parameter error.

I then tried, -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule, command line on Server2:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver60,computerName=Server1 -dest:webserver60 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -whatif > msdeploy_test.log.
```

This returned no error, but the log file still shows deleting all existing app pools on Server2.

Any help in migrating all the sites on the Server1 to Server2 and keeping all the sites and app pools on Server2?  Thank you.